# Jquery form with recaptcha serialization problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, recaptcha

Trying to serialize a form with recaptcha in the form.

Here is how I serialize my form:

```
var serializedform = $('form.af').serialize();
```

Here is my form example:

```
<form class = 'af'>
    <input name='name' id = 'name'>
    <input name='lastname' id = 'lastname'>
        <div id = 'recaptchadiv'>
            <input name='recaptcha_response_field' id = 'recaptcha_response_field'>
            <input name='recaptcha_challenge_field' id = 'recaptcha_challenge_field'>
            <noscript>
                <input name='recaptcha_response_field' id = 'recaptcha_response_field'>
                <input name='recaptcha_challenge_field' id = 'recaptcha_challenge_field'>
            </noscript>
        </div>
    <button name = 'submit'>
</form>
```

problem comes from recaptcha noscript block injected by recaptcha automatically. 
That block contains a copy of recaptcha_response_field and recaptcha_challenge_field.

So -  when I serialize this form  - values from noscript block inputs overwrite real recaptcha_response_field and  recaptcha_challenge_field values.

Is there a way to serialize a form using jquery while skipping noscript block?

Thanks:)

Comment: Why not serialize separate field values: name, lastname, response, chanllenge?

Comment: thanks. i can definately do that, but the actual form is quite big. This is just a small example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use jQuery to [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove) the `<noscript>` tags before the form is serialized - clearly, they aren't necessary by that point. Something like this:

```
var $form = $('form.af');
$form.find('noscript').remove();
var serializedform = $form.serialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the noscript tags shouldn't even be present in the DOM in the first place so there should be no need to remove them. See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4m3P/).

Are you sure that the contents of your noscript tags get serialized?

Comment: yep. i'm sure. @Matt Ball's advice fixed it. Not sure if it has something do do with that I generate recaptcha via php.

Comment: @Andre: Do you also see the second field in my demo?

Comment: i checked out the demo and yes - your demo gets serialized without noscript elements. I think perhaps I might have an issue with how my php generates recaptcha. I'll try to look into this a bit later..too tired right now:) Thanks for your advice though.